# Handling event raised by a device in separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-handling

I have written a C# application which is working with 2 devices attached viz. a digital microscope which shows image and a counting device which returns me a counter. Both these devices are running simultaneously and generate events indicating changes in images and counter values.

Microscope generates below event:

```
void _ImageCaptured(object source, WebcamEventArgs e)
{
}  

And counter generates below event:
void _OnRegisterValueChanged(object sender, RegisterChangeEventArgs args)
{
}
```

Being a single threaded application, my current application is not able to get images and counter values at the same speed and there is some lag between them. I want to make this application multi-threaded and handle both these events in separate thread. Appreciate any help for achieving this.

Comment: You may not have created threads, but generally the C# events are executed from the ThreadPool. So what is generating the events? Do you do some beginRead() or beginReceive()? Or are you calling invoke() from your event handlers and by doing so handling them on the UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

So this means that you're going to separate the logic to be run in two different threads from the initialization point - then you'll receive each notification in different threads - each in one, where the event is being fired. Then if you'll need to share some data between those events - just syncronize on it and that's it.